# Apache WSGI + Flask, get 404 error

Tags: apache2, flask

I tried to set up a hello world Flask app on Apache, following [its document](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/deploying/mod_wsgi/).

What I got is,

```
% cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/flask.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>

    WSGIScriptAlias /py /var/www/py/wsgi.py
    <Directory /var/www/py>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

% cat /var/www/py/wsgi.py 
from app import app as application

% cat /var/www/py/app.py 
from Flask import flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
  return 'hello wsgi'
```

I've `a2ensite flask` and reload Apache. But I got a 404 error from Apache when I tried to visit `localhost/py`

```
% a2query -m wsgi
wsgi (enabled by maintainer script)

% apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 24 2015 15:59:00

% pip show flask
---
Metadata-Version: 1.1
Name: Flask
Version: 0.10.1
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so it seems that somehow `flask.conf` is not working on its own. I just append `flask.conf` to the default configure `000-default.conf` and it works happily. And I definitely `a2ensite flask`ed. Really weird.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/780249/why-do-some-some-files-in-etc-have-a-numeric-prefix

Comment: can you show your `000-default.conf`

Comment: @pyd Sorry but it has been lost.